# Date Error when running a SQL Query in Excel

Tags: sql, excel, date

When running a SQL query in an Excel macro enabled workbook it displays the date value wrong in excel but shows the correct date in the Power Query Editor. I have created the same query in a new workbook and I don't get the same error? It is off by 1461 days.  Any suggestions?

Snapshot of Issue
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Excel supports two different date systems. These systems are the 1900 date system and the 1904 date system.

In the 1900 date system, the first day that is supported is January 1, 1900.

In the 1904 date system, the first day that is supported is January 1, 1904.

See https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/214330/differences-between-the-1900-and-the-1904-date-system-in-excel and https://support.office.com/en-us/article/date-systems-in-excel-e7fe7167-48a9-4b96-bb53-5612a800b487

The difference between the two date systems is 1,462 days; that is, the serial number of a date in the 1900 Date System is always 1,462 days bigger than the serial number of the same date in the 1904 date system. And this is exactly the difference between the dates in Excel sheet and Power Query showed in your picture.

The Excel sheet you are showing runs in  the 1904 date system while your Power Query Editor uses 1900 date system.

Example: `11/8/2017` has serial number 43047 in 1900 date system. The same serial number in 1904 date system points to 1462 days later which is `11/9/2021`.

The linked articles also show how to change the date system for the workbook.